# How to create triangle inside triangle with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, triangle

I was trying to create triangle inside triangle which looks like this and I dont know how to do that properly with usage of recursion. Please give me some advice, I am hopeless [Triangle picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Enh.png)

Comment: Looks similar to a Sierpinski Triangle.  That would be a good place to start.

Comment: That is called the [medial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle). At each step, you replace the vertices `a, b, c` with `(b+c)/2, (c+a)/2, (a+b)/2`.

Comment: I already did Sierpinski triangle, but this is more difficult, i dont know how to do that triangles in the middle :)

Answer (score 0):

You should find a mid-point for every 3 points of the triangle using this:

```
midPoint1x = (x1+x2)/2 , midPoint1y = (y1+y2)/2
midPoint2x = (x1+x3)/2 , midPoint2y = (y1+y3)/2
midPoint3x = (x3+x2)/2 , midPoint3y = (y3+y2)/2
```

Then you should create a triangle with these 3 mid-points.

Now, you can call it recursively with new mid-points.